# Timer In AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timer, angularjs-scope, angular-timer

Why is my timer tag not working in Angularjs? I used the following code

```
<timer interval="1000" countdown="100">{{countdown}}</timer>
```

Also, how to alert the timer minutes and seconds while I click the get time button given in the plunker?

Here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/u4kaFALY0TkUxipjvG0p?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Include your script *after* including libraries like jQuery / angular:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8824346/angular-timer.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script> <!-- Moved this one after the libraries above. -->
```

[Updated, working plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/QNW4MgbJwHuK9D7lb4cA?p=preview)

Comment: @RamanaUday why don't give it a try yourself? It helps learning and understanding. If you have a specific question or problem, please create a new post.

Comment: I have been trying for almost 2 hours with different functionality but not working please can u help me regarding this @nilsK